# How do I link two properties to one class but only being able to reference to one in EFC Code First?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have two Classes:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public User Wingman { get; set; }
}
```

Trying to add a migration understandably i get the following error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'User.UserProfile' of type 'UserProfile'. Either manually
>   configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
>   '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
>   'OnModelCreating'.

`UserProfile.User` is the user itself and `UserProfile.Wingman` is another user representig the wingman.
Do i need another Table for that like a bridge or is there another way to resolve that problem? 
And I don't need to reference `Wingman` from the `User`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [InversePropertyAttribute](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/inverseproperty-attribute) or the Fluent API config methods `HasOne`/`WithOne` or `HasOne/WithMany` with appropriate property selectors.

If you’re looking for a 1:1 relationship, use a shard primary key - make the PK for UserProfile the FK to User.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
    .HasOne( up => up.User )
    .WithOne( u => u.UserProfile )
    .HasForeignKey( up => up.UserProfileId ); // I suggest renaming PK to UserId for clarity
```

If 1:N relationship, two ways; first, w/ `InversePropertyAttribute`:

```
public class User
{
    ...
    [InverseProperty( "User" )]
    public ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Or via Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserProfile>()
    .HasOne( up => up.User )
    .WithMany( u => u.UserProfiles );
```